# Proper way to validate data and save it to db for realtime app

Tags: javascript, php, node.js, laravel, socket.io

For example i build chat app based on laravel + node.js server.
What is the best idea for creating new message:

1. Emit msg to server -> validate it and add it to db via node.js -> return msg to all users
2. Make api in laravel for validation and db -> using ajax (i think this is not best idea)
3. Make api in laravel for validation and db -> emit msg to server -> request in node.js to api in laravel -> return msg to all users
4. Other?

Comment: Why you need laravel if you are working with a node.js app? Why just use socket.io and node to manage the messages event and serve the html files (if is needed?)

Comment: @msdark im more familiar with laravel and i have actually written some code in it, so i dont want to transfer all code to node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do like this:

### 1 - Validate msg with Node.js and immediately broadcast when valid.

You can make use of Node.js events and EventsEmitter and react to each new msg. Also with this approach you will be broadcasting the msg to all users as soon as valid.

### 2 - Save validated msg to db calling a Laravel API trough Node.js

Once your message has been broadcasted now you can save to db by calling a Laravel API inside your Node.js app.

```
var events = require('events');
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

function saveToDb() {
  // call to api here
}

function validate(msg) {
  //validate msg
  return valid;
}


eventEmitter.on('msgBroadcasted', saveToDb);
eventEmitter.on('msgBroadcasted', anotherFunction);


socket.on('new message', function (data) {
  if (!validate(data)) { return false }

  socket.broadcast.emit('new message', {
    username: socket.username,
    message: data
  });
  return eventEmitter.emit('msgBroadcasted');
});
```

Comment: Answers that depend on code from external links should be included in the answer body, since if the link goes dead, the answer becomes meaningless in the future.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Probably i use this method in my app, but i'll wait for more solutions. If nothing happens i accept your answer.